# Where is the Weblogic Worklist Menu Located in Weblogic 8.1

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic8.x

I am trying to delete an active task in Weblogic 8.1. As per bea/oracle documentation this can be possible from Weblogic Worklist Admintration as mentioned in the following link. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13214_01/wli/docs81/manage/worklist.html

But I am not able to find the Worklist Administration inside Weblogic Administration. Can you please let me know if the console is in a separate path?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's on a separate URL: `http://adminserver:port/wliconsole`

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13214_01/wli/docs81/manage/intro.html#1033708 for more details.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Can we delete the task from the Worklist Administration by changing the State to "Not Existing" as mentioned in the document http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13214_01/wli/docs81/worklist/tasks.html#1060886. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hi Sambaran, I'm afraid I really can't remember - it's 9 or 10 years since I last had any exposure to WLI (I had to look up the context name for the console it's been so long!).  However, I wouldn't have said just setting the state would be right, the Task Worker control (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13214_01/wli/docs81/worklist/controls.html#1078302) seems to have a deleteTask method.  Apologies for not being more helpful.